# C# System.Threading.Timer Recursive Updates

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a once Timer that calls a function every 15 seconds, it works for the first 5 times, but then does not elapse for the 6th, even though it is created, any ideas?

The processing time could take longer than 15 seconds, if so Thread A could be processing data while Thread B sends out a new request for data. Thread B cannot start until the processing of Thread A has finished.

```
const int DATAREFRESH = 15000;

void RequestUpdate()
{
    // Some data processing goes here
    Console.WriteLine("Update");

    // Set the timer
    Timer t = new Timer(new TimerCallback(TimeOutCallback), null, DATAREFRESH, Timeout.Infinite);
}

private void TimeOutCallback(object state)
{
    RequestUpdate();
}
```

In the Output window, "Update" is displayed 5 times, then after then, nothing. It hasnt frozen, I see that ~8 threads terminate after the last "Update".

How can I get this to work infinitely?

Comment: Please use a title that describes the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Which `Timer` class are you using?

Comment: And why don't you create a single timer instance and reset it in the callback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems very weird to instantiate a new timer from within the callback. A more realistic example would be one in which you are performing the work inside the timer callback. Also you seem to be incorrectly calling the `Timer` constructor. If you want the callback to execute at regular intervals (15 seconds in your case) you could use the following:

```
const int DATAREFRESH = 15000;
private Timer _timer;

void RequestUpdate()
{
    // Set the timer
    _timer = new Timer(TimeOutCallback, null, 0, DATAREFRESH);
}

private void TimeOutCallback(object state)
{
    // Some data processing goes here
    Console.WriteLine("Update");
}
```

Also notice how I have inverted the arguments passed to the timer so that it executes the callback every 15 seconds.

Comment: @craig1231, notice how I have inverted the arguments: `new Timer(TimeOutCallback, null, 0, DATAREFRESH);`. Now the timer will execute the callback at regular intervals.

Comment: This looks like something along the right lines, but I have updated the problem above.

Comment: @craig1231, I don't understand your update. In your previous comment you talked about indefinite processing of the timer, now you start talking about some thread B sending some *requests* (what requests?) about some *data* (what data?). I am totally lost at what you are trying to do and what your problem is. Maybe if you provided a more realistic example your question would have made more sense to me.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the OP's key problem, the timer *still* stops ticking.

Comment: @HansPassant, I must confess that I am totally lost at what the OP's problem is now. Maybe you are correct. I just don't know what problem we are trying to solve here as we don't have a real example and context.

Comment: @Darin I do appreciate your help. Im requesting some data from a server and processing it. I cannot request data again for another 15 seconds, but the processing time could > 15 seconds.

Comment: @craig1231, then why are you using a Timer??? Why aren't you using a producer/consumer pattern? Take a look at the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) for examples of implementing this pattern. Seems like you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @craig1231, then I invite you to read about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the garbage collector has deleted the timer object.  This problem got started by declaring the timer reference as a *local variable*.  After the RequestUpdate() method exits there are no references left to the timer.  Not even the callback provides a reference, a bit unusual but makes it consistent with timers that have a static callback method and avoids leaks.

The simple fix is to make it a field of your class:

```
private Timer dataRefreshTimer;

void RequestUpdate()
{
    dataRefreshTimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(TimeOutCallback), null, 0, DATAREFRESH);
}
```

Which ensures that the timer lives at least as long as the class that contains the callback method.

Notable is that the System.Timers.Timer class doesn't have this same problem.  The CLR ensures that such timers stay referenced for as long as they are enabled.  But don't use it, its otherwise not a very good timer.

Comment: What if the timer is set within a static class as a static variable, is this good?